# How configure Web.Config document for a simple web application in ASP.NET MVC 3 once uploaded it to my host

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have built a default web application in ASP.NET MVC 3 and I have uploaded it to my host.

All work fine, however when I try logging in, or do an action with the default database "ASPNETDB.MDF" I get the following error:

```
Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
```

The Host have support for SQL Server 2008 and this is the default connectionString created in Web.Config document by visualstudio 2010 SP1(ASP.NET MVC 3, Framework 4.0):

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank You

Comment: does your host support sql server? have you tried contacting them?